# Col BY causing parse error in Google sheets query

Tags: google-sheets, syntax, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language, reserved-words

I'm trying to run the following Query in google sheets, but am receiving a parse error when I try to select the column BY. Without this column, it runs as expected.

Query below:

```
=QUERY('Applications received'!B:DL,"Select B,CT,CU,CV,CW,CX,BY where B is not null order by CX")
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BY column needs to be escaped with <kbd>`</kbd>:

```
=QUERY('Applications received'!B:DL,
 "select B,CT,CU,CV,CW,CX,`BY` 
  where B is not null 
  order by CX")
```

[image]

**https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#reserved-words**